# Select the last match per group while using "Before" parameter

Tags: awk, grep

I have a text file that looks something like this...

```
<title> south asia </title>
India is country that is part of south asia.
<title> africa </title>
kenya is a country that is part of africa.
```

This command works as expected and returns the correct category...

> grep -B1 'kenya' wiki.txt | grep title

But this trick will not work if the text file looks something like this...

```
<title> south asia </title>
India is country that is part of south asia.
<title> africa </title>
List of countries:
kenya is a country that is part of africa.
```

If I do not know the correct value for "Before" parameter, then I get extra (wrong) titles.

```
# grep -B5 'kenya' wiki.txt | grep title
<title> south asia </title>
<title> africa </title>
```

Is it possible to select the last "title" per group while using -B parameter?

Expected:
The line **title africa title** should be returned for the word ***"kenya"*** even if I do not know the number of lines used in the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `awk` simply store the `title` records in a variable (`t`) and print them when you encounter the matching word (variable `w`):

```
$ awk -vw='kenya' '/<title>/ {t=$0} $0~w {print t}' wiki.txt
<title> africa </title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tac` + `awk` solution, written and tested with your shown attempts and samples.

```
tac Input_file | 
awk -F'>[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]*<' '
/kenya/{
  found=1
  next
}
found && /\<title\>/{
  print
  found=""
}
'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
tac Input_file |                        ##Using tac to print file from bottom to top and sending its output as input to awk program.
awk -F'>[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]*<' '   ##Starting awk program setting field separator to >[[:space:]]+ OR [[:space:]]*< here.
/kenya/{                                ##Checking condition if word kenya is found in line.
  found=1                               ##Setting found to 1 here.
  next                                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
found && /\<title\>/{                   ##Checking if found is SET and it contains title.
  print                                 ##Printing current line.
  found=""                              ##Nullifying found here.
}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take the last line of output:

```sh
grep -B5 'kenya' wiki.txt | grep title | tail -n 1
```